# How to get landline output to pc?

Tags: audio-recording, phone

My landline phone has a line in and line out port. The phone line from the provider is connected to line in port.

My laptop doesn't have a phone line cable port but only an ethernet port.

Is there a way I can get my phone audio to my pc for recording?

I have heard that if you can get the audio to your sound card your pc can record it. Can ethernet port take the sound output from line out port to my sound card using a port converter?

Please also mention any software required.

Comment: An ethernet port can only handle ethernet, nothing else. What you need is a "pickup" that you then connect to your mic or line-in port (something like https://www.amazon.com/Telephone-Microphone-Suction-Cup-Pickup/dp/B0034I75IK?language=en_US).